# Creating a dictionary in julia using set of arrays as keys and values?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have used the following code to create a dictionary using arrays as keys and values.

For Example:

```
k = [1,2,3,4]
v = [2,3,4,5]

for i in 1:length(k)
    get!(d, k[i], v[i])
end

#Output
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 4 entries:
  4 => 5
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  1 => 2
```

May I know is there any simpler approach (preferably single line) to achieve this operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> Dict(zip(k,v))
Dict{Int64, Int64} with 4 entries:
  4 => 5
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  1 => 2
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, highly appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use broadcasting on the pair operator:

```
julia> Dict(k .=> v)
Dict{Int64, Int64} with 4 entries:
  4 => 5
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  1 => 2
```

Comment: This works, too, but has one extra intermediate array allocation, and is slightly slower.